# Handler doesn't update UI elements

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I use a Handler to update my UI from an IntentService object, however, it looks like the runnable gets executed, the UI doesn't get updated. This is how my code looks like :

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                Log.d("DemoApp", getTitle());

                title.setText(getTitle());
            }
        });
```

Result : It prints the title, but nothing happens with the UI. What is this?

Comment: is `title` attached to the View's Hierarchy ?

Comment: so you are not inflating it from scratch ?

Comment: No, actually, for the first time it shows the recent information, but at the second call not.

Comment: Don't you have any other idea(s)?

Comment: Service has no ui. Rethink your design

Answer (score -1):

Try running on UI thread

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            Log.d("DemoApp", getTitle());

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    title.setText(getTitle());
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: I wanted to do that, but runOnUiThread is not available from a Service.

Comment: Then use a BroadCastReceiver, send the value from the service and on the activity show the title, its possible?

Comment: are you really in a Service's subclass ?